# create non visual activex control with delphi

Tags: delphi, activex, controls

i was created a nonvisual vcl component in delphi and I'm trying to make it usable for other environment like visual studio, and i think the best way is create an activex control. but the problem is i haven't any experience about creating activex in delphi. i found some resource by google about creating activex in delphi but most of them work on visual controls but my component is non visual... anyway i hope someone help me in clear way to do this.

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@cyberw0lf,  check this link [how to develop activex invisible component library in delphi](http://www.2p.cz/files/2p.cz/downloads/howto/activex_delphi_invisible_component_library.pdf)
this is a step by step tutorial to make an invisible activex  control, you can find the source code [here](http://www.2p.cz/files/2p.cz/downloads/delphi/activex_delphi_invisible_component.zip).

i hope will be useful for you ;)