# delphi graphical component to activex

Tags: delphi, components, activex, graphic

I made a graphical component which ancestor has to be TGraphiccontrol because I need to paint to the canvas.
Now I want to convert this component to an activex control but that seems to be only possible when the component is a descendant from TWincontrol.
How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What makes you think you cannot paint on a windowed control?

Comment: Use `TCustomControl` it is `TWinControl` descendant with `Canvas`

Comment: See also [How to write Delphi ActiveX control which can be used in MS Word/Excel/Powerpoint?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19112324/757830)

Comment: Thanks all for your help. Indeed I can take TCustomControl instead of TGaphicControl. Then I don't get a compile error and it works.

Answer (score 5):

It is incorrect that you must only use a `TGraphicControl` in order to paint. Base your control on `TCustomControl` instead. This provides you with a canvas which you can use the same way, and is inherited from the `TWinControl`.